# vimscript: make a key mapping works only in a specified buffer

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'a writing a plugin. I opened a buffer, and drap some menu items in it. I want to trigger some special function when a enter key is pressed. I used nmap  :func() , but enter key triggered the func in other buffers as well.
Can anybody tell me how to do keymapping that works only in the specified buffer?
Or any ideas about how to make a menu is welcome, I don't have any experience in writing plugins before.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Dean

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict a keymapping to the current buffer by adding `<buffer>` to the mapping, like this:

`nmap <buffer> <CR> :call func()<CR>`

See `:help map-arguments` for details.
You can add menu items to the main menu via the `amenu` command:

`amenu &MyMenu.MyMenu&Item :call MyFunc()<CR>`

This command adds a new menu `MyMenu` and a new menu item `MyMenuItem` to MyMenu.
You can remove the menu item (or the whole menu) via the `aunmenu` command.
See `:help amenu` and `:help aunmenu` for details.